# RxJs7 deprecated throwError

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I've been following the NestJS course and during the section about Interceptors we need to create a TimeoutInterceptor as so:

```ts
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(3000),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But my VSCode tells me throwError has been deprecated in RxJs v7, so I've come with the following solution:

```ts
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(3000),
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          throw new RequestTimeoutException();
        }

        throw new Error(err);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I haven't found anything on the NestJS documentation that seems up to date and the method still seems to work even if it's deprecated, so I was wondering if my solution is viable and safe for production environments or if should I stick to the official NestJS documentation? Or maybe there's another better solution that I just haven't found yet online...

Thanks in advance for taking the time of answering me.

Comment: I just found this in official RxJS documentation: here is the example link: https://stackblitz.com/run?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts and here is the link of documentation https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError#unnecessary-usage

Comment: It's not deprecated, just this declaration is deprecated. You need to pass a function that returns an error.

Comment: Ohhhh it makes total sense I think @martin! Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: I found the update to the syntax odd (i.e. throwError with anonymous function within) - so when I read the link to the documentation - they actually seem to be saying you should just do a vanilla throw - so I think just "throw err;" would've worked in this scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change it to.

```js
    export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        return next.handle().pipe(
          timeout(3000),
          catchError(err => {
            if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
              return throwError(() => new RequestTimeoutException());
            }
            return throwError(() => err);
          }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see thanks! Totally glossed over it while reading the RxJs documentation I stopped my self at       // This is probably overkill. part :)

Thanks!